# Reference table and form text box MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Pardon the code below. I am a VBA novice. I am looking to upon clicking a form button, inform customers that they must make another library selection if the item they have chosen is checked out. I determine something is checked out if the "Check In Date" for the most recent date in the "1Transaction" table is NULL. Note for every check in and check out, a new record is created in the 1Transaction table and every record (whether check in or check out) will have the check out date info. So the logic, take the most recent date for the lease (book) number and if there is no return date then it is still checked out. The code below is meant to make the references and return a message box in VBA but I am stuck. I understand logically what I require but I know my VBA syntax is very off. Thanks.

```
Private Sub Check_Out()

 If [1Transactions].[Asset].Value = Me.Lease_Num
  And DMax([Tables]![1Transactions].[Check Out Date])
  And [Tables]![1Transactions].[Check In Date] = NULL
 Then MsgBox "The requested documents are currently checked out"
 End If
 DoCmd.OpenForm "Check In"

End Sub
```

### Note:

- 1Transactions = Table holding all check in/out data
- Me.Lease_Num = value pulled from combo box that user fills out to provide "lease number" (book code) they are interested in checking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay - instead of trying to modify every line of your code, I think it's better to use a Parameter Query to simple check if the item is out now

First create a query using your transactions table - modify the SQL to below 
and save it as "**qdfLease**"

```
PARAMETERS [What Lease Num] Text ( 255 ); SELECT TOP 1
[1Transactions].Asset, [1Transactions].[Check Out Date],
[1Transactions].[Check In Date] FROM 1Transactions WHERE
([1Transactions].Asset = [What Lease Num]) And ([1Transactions].[Check
In Date] Is Null) ORDER BY [1Transactions].[Check Out Date] DESC;
```

Modify the code in your sub to:

```
Dim qdf             As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs              As DAO.Recordset
Dim strLeaseNum     As String

strLeaseNum = nz(Me.Lease_Num,"")
Set qdfLease = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qdfLease")
qdfLease.Parameters("What Lease Num") = strLeaseNum
Set rs = qdfLease.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
If rs.EOF Then
    ' Item is Checked In
Else
    ' Item is Checked Out
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

You have `[1Transactions].[Check Out Date].Value = Me.Lease_Num`

Is that what you want to compare the lease_num to? It sounds like it should be a different field name in [1Transactions]

I would change this

`[Tables]![1Transactions].[Check In Date] = NULL`

to this

`IsNull([Tables]![1Transactions].[Check In Date])`

What are you trying to compare here

`DMax([Tables]![1Transactions].[Check Out Date])`

Comment: `[1Transactions].[Check Out Date].Value = Me.Lease_Num`  Here I am trying to subset the 1Transactions Table where the lease number is equal to that which was selected by the customer in a combo box ( Me.lease_num) - `DMax([Tables]![1Transactions].[Check Out Date])` here I am trying to pull the maximum date for the lease number that was selected in the combo box ( Lease_Num) - Thanks

Comment: What I'm saying is ... 1Transactions must have a LeaseNum field doesn't it? Why don't you use that to compare to your Lease_Num combo box? Right now you are comparing it to [1Transactions].[Check Out Date].Value - which I assume is a date and not a library number

Comment: I see what you are saying. Apologies. Long day. I am actually referencing the `Assets` field in `[1Transactions]` . Typo on my end.